# Is there a way to make a textbox save by itself?

Tags: python, tkinter, logic, tkinter-text

So let's say I wanted to make a code editor and I want the contents in a text box to save by itself.

How would I do that, and where would I start?

Here is my thought:
I would create a function that saves the content and run it in a forever loop. But it won't work, so how would I do it.

Comment: You can use the universal widget [`after()`](https://web.archive.org/web/20190222214221id_/http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/universal.html) method to schedule a function to be called after a given delay. The callback function can also call it to cause itself to be called again (forever).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Step one: make a function that saves the data:

```
def save():
    data = the_text_widget.get("1.0", "end-1c")
    with open("the_filename.txt", "w") as f:
        f.write(data)
```

Next, write a function that calls this function over some interval, like every 10 seconds:

```
def autosave():
    save()
    the_text_widget.after(10000, autosave)
```

And finally, call this function once and it will run every 10 seconds:

```
autosave()
```

This isn't the only way, but it's arguably the simplest.

Comment: Code Pez dispenser?  You know this is a bad question, no effort at all.  You should know better.

Comment: @TomServo: sometimes people need a little boost. AFAIK there isn't a question about automatically saving a text widget on this site so I thought it was worth answering.

Comment: Wouldn’t it be better to bind the function AutoSave() every time a keyboard button is pressed, benefits are, 1 it stops unnecessary calls of AutoSave, and 2 it would be certain that all text would be saved, incase the text editor is closed before the next 10 second interval.

Comment: @coderoftheday: That depends on how you define "better". Certainly there are other ways to do it, but for a beginner, and for a hobby-level text editor, this works fine.